# Add active class for the list of buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add active class to the list of buttons. Is there any JavaScript for active the button class?

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <button class="filter-button btn" data-filter="all"><span class="caps">A</span>ll</button>
    <button class="filter-button btn" data-filter="category1"><span class="caps">C</span>ataract</button>
    <button class="filter-button btn" data-filter="category2"><span class="caps">L</span>asik</button>
    <button class="filter-button btn" data-filter="category3"><span class="caps">O</span>phthalmology</button>
    <button class="filter-button btn" data-filter="category4"><span class="caps">G</span>laucoma</button>
    <button class="filter-button btn" data-filter="category5"><span class="caps">R</span>etina</button>
    <button class="filter-button btn" data-filter="category6"><span class="caps">O</span>pticaI lens</button>
</div>
```

I want to set the button to active on clicking.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery:

`$(document).ready(function() {
    var buttons = $('.btn');
    buttons.change(function() {
        //$('.btn.active').removeClass('active'); //Uncomment this line if you want to remove active class from other buttons if another button is pressed.
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});`

Answer (score -1):

use jquery add class and remove class function something like this  :

$("your_list_id ").click(function(){

```
if ($(this).find('#menu li').hasClass('active')) {
    //console.log("Active class seen");
    $(this).find('#menu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

});